# Prove: $|x|-|y|\leq |x-y|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Can you help me proving this equality?
$$|x|-|y|\leq |x-y|$$

I think that it's possible to give a too short proof if the things are written correctly.

Comment: Do you know the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$|x|=|(x-y)+y|$$
Now apply the triangle inequality.

PS: by symmetry you conclude that on the left hand side, you can even put an absolute value around the difference.

Answer (score 0):

$$|x|-|y|\leq |x-y| \Leftrightarrow |x|\le|y|+ |x-y|$$
Use $|a|+|b|\ge|a+b|$
$$|y|+ |x-y|\ge |y+ x-y|=|x|$$